# How do I make a back button for a Ruby on Rails app that functions like a native iOS or Android app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm wanting to make a back button throughout my web app that should only show up on pages past the `root_path`. Right now it's implemented with:

```
<%= link_to "Back", :back, :class => "navbar-brand" %>
```

It's sitting in my navigation, within the header partial file, which is called from the application.html.erb file. That means the back button shows up on every page, including the home page.

Will some sort of `unless` statement work so that it shows up on all pages aside from the home page? I'm thinking:

```
<% unless root_path? %>
  <%= link_to "Back", :back, :class => "navbar-brand" %>
<% end %>
```

But that doesn't work. Any suggestions on how to write that statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `request` object. In your application helper:

```
def root_path?
  request.path == "/" ? true : false
end
```

Answer (score 1):

@Cortex has a good answer. Alternatively, if there are a number of "root pages" as their would be in an iOS app, you can use

`params[:controller]`, `params[:action]` , or `controller_path` to give you a higher degree of precision.

Comment: my app is evolving to have a number of root pages. How would I implement your solution? Would `params[:controller]` check for one of my controllers? ie: `params[:events]` or `params[:events#index]`?